# merging multiple rows into one row with multiple colums

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I found this query about merging various rows and columns into on row.

```
SELECT `studentdata`.`FirstName`,`studentdata`.`LastName`,`grades`.`idClass`, `term`.`TermName`,  
JAVA.ExamGrade AS JAVA, JAVA.CourseWork AS JAVACW
```

From Grades
    LEFT JOIN `ereportv3`.`studentdata` ON `grades`.`StudentID` = `studentdata`.`StudentID`
    LEFT JOIN `ereportv3`.`term` ON `grades`.`idTerm` = `term`.`IdTerm`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN grades JAVA ON (grades.StudentID=JAVA.StudentID AND JAVA.idSubject='JAVA')
    WHERE grades.idTerm = '5'  and grades.idClass = 'JAVA1' AND  `studentdata`.`idStatus`='Active'
  Group by `studentdata`.`StudentID`
Order by `studentdata`.`LastName`

The problem I am getting is that when I the query is run I am given all the records for java for that class in that table instead of just the records of that class for that specified term. I am not sure what I need to do to fix it. I have looked around for a solution but I am yet to come across one that works as I would like. Can someone help or suggest an alternative ??

The results I am getting without the group by syntax is

---

FirstName  LastName  idClass  TermName    Java  JavaCW 
  John        Doe     Java1    Jan-Mar    33     45
  John        Doe     Java1    Jan-Mar    0      66

Which is all the existing records for the person in the table

What i actually need is it to show this data only

FirstName  LastName  idClass  TermNam    Java  JavaCW 
  John        Doe     Java1    Jan-Mar    0      66

Which is the actual data for that course for that student in that term. ( Sorry about the formatting not sure how to put it in a table format)

Comment: You are going to get an sql syntax error message, not any records for the query in the OP. Where is before group by. Can you pls paste the actual query you are trying to run?

Comment: Also, pls post some sample data, results you are getting, and the expected results

Comment: where is your `from` clause?

Comment: SELECT `studentdata`.`FirstName`,`studentdata`.`LastName`,`grades`.`idClass`, `term`.`TermName`,  
JAVA.ExamGrade AS JAVA, JAVA.CourseWork AS JAVACW
FROM grades 
LEFT JOIN `ereportv3`.`studentdata` ON `grades`.`StudentID` = `studentdata`.`StudentID`  
LEFT JOIN `ereportv3`.`term` ON `grades`.`idTerm` = `term`.`IdTerm`  
LEFT OUTER JOIN grades JAVA ON (grades.StudentID=JAVA.StudentID AND JAVA.idSubject='JAVA') 
WHERE grades.idTerm = '5'  and grades.idClass = 'JAVA1' AND  `studentdata`.`idStatus`='Active' 
Group by `studentdata`.`StudentID` 
Order by `studentdata`.`LastName`